# Is it possible to determine if Adobe AIR app is running from browser?

Tags: javascript, flash, browser, adobe, air

Is it possible to determine if Adobe AIR app is running from browser?

So I want to check if app is on, how to do such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the things you can do with a custom AIR install badge. You can't necessarily detect that a given AIR app is running, but you can detect whether or not it's installed, and either install or launch (if already installed) from the browser. If the app is already running, it will receive the ACTIVATE event.

There's a post about it from Adobe here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/badge_for_air.html

Answer (score 1):

AIR is not a browser based solution. AIR is a desktop solution. Perhaps you could rephrase your question?